# R: Plot multiple maps in a grid from a single shapefile

Tags: r, for-loop, geography

I have a single shapefile with polygon boundaries for the top 30 most-populous cities in the United States. I'd like to loop over the shapefile in R and plot a map of each city in a 5 x 6 grid with their names at the top of each grid. Each row has a NAME field for the place and a UniqueID (0:29), among other fields, such as POPULATION, SQMILES, etc. I have no problem subsetting the shapefile and plot single cities. I'm struggling with the for loop, however. Any tips would be appreciated, especially if you also have thoughts about rendering each city footprint in a constant bounding box so each city's respective boundaries are proportional to one another.

Comment: Without the shapefile and some semblance at a bit of code, I fear this question may get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that plots the first 16 states of North Carolina in a 4 x 4 grid:

```
library(maptools)
nc <- readShapePoly(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1], proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27"))
par(mfrow=c(4,4))
for(i in 1:16) { plot(nc[i,]); title(nc$NAME[i]) }
```